# How to do test integration of features based on delayed jobs with cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, delayed-job, capybara, email-spec

I want to test some features that needs delayed jobs to work, on cucumber. I have defined the following step:

```
Given /^jobs are being dispatched$/ do 
    Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
end
```

Right now, I am trying to test email notifications. So I have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Receiving email when signing up   
      Given I am on the signup page
      And I fill in "user[email]" with "test@test.com" 
      And I fill in "user[password]" with "password"
      And I fill in "user[password_confirmation]" with "password"
      And I press "Sign up"
      Then I should be on the homepage
      Given jobs are being dispatched
      Then "test@test.com" should receive 1 emails
```

The *should receive n emails* step is defined by [email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) and is defined as:

```
Then /^(?:I|they|"([^"]*?)") should receive (an|no|\d+) emails?$/ do |address, amount|
  unread_emails_for(address).size.should == parse_email_count(amount)
end
```

So the test fails telling me that I am receiving 0 emails (the test@test.com is replaced by a real email in this test and I am not receiving anything). I suspect that the worker didn't really start. What should I check? By the way, when I test in development mode I really receive that email.

Thanks

**Edit:**

It looks like I am getting a *SQLite3::BusyException*:

> SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ....

Now to investigate why and how I can get rid of that! Any idea? (besides moving my database to PostgreSQL or mySQL).

**Edit:**
Ok, I moved to PostgreSQL from SQLite, the records are being inserted into `Delayed::Job` but the email tests fail.

The config/environments/test.rb file contains:

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port                 => 587,
     :domain               => "mydomain.com",
     :user_name            => "name@mydomain.com",
     :password             => "mypassword",
     :authentication       => "plain",
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: What is config.action_mailer.delivery_method set to in config.rb? Is a record being inserted into the delayed_jobs table?

Comment: @Andy - Looks like the record is not inserted because of the SQLite3::BusyException.

Comment: Ok the record are being inserted into the delayed_job table but the tests are still failling. I added the content of the config/environments/test.rb file.

Comment: @AmokraneChentir while this is old, I'm getting the same behavior with mysql, where jobs are in the db but they are not getting worked on. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the answer is to move off of sqlite.  Delayed job locks the database so your app gets staved.

Comment: Yep that what's I ended up doing (moving to PostgreSQL).